# Show a specific day of the week based on today's date

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

Hi everyone I'm working with '`Calendar`' and I'm trying to find the right way and an elegant way to get the Tuesday of the next week only if today's date is a Sunday or Monday.

For example, if today is Sunday I would like to show the next available date on the following Tuesday

For now I have done this but I wanted to know if there is a right and more elegant way (i don't know if using `DateInterval` would be better)

```
enum WeekdaysRef: Int { case Dom = 1, Lun, Mar, Mer, Gio, Ven, Sab }

extension Date {
    
     func startDate(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        
        let sunday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: self) == WeekdaysRef.Dom.rawValue
        let monday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: self) == WeekdaysRef.Lun.rawValue

        return sunday ? today(adding: 2) : Monday ? today(adding: 1) : self
    }

     func today(adding: Int, _ calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: adding, to: self)!
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you only care to show the Tuesday if it's a Sunday? What's the actual format you're going for? What should it show if it's a Monday, or a Wednesday?

Comment: @xTwisteDx Let me explain I'm working with LazyVGrid to show a calendar in swiftUI. Now the selected day as soon as the user opens the app and the current day. I need to show the calendar selection on Tuesday only if the current day is Sunday or Monday otherwise the calendar must show the selection for the current day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a custom enum for this, check if the week day is 1 or 2 and then return next Tuesday

```
func nextTuesday(after date: Date, using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date? {
    let weekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
    return weekday > 2 ? nil : calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: weekday % 2 + 1, to: date)
}
```

Note that I use a standalone function here and return nil if the in date isn't Sunday or Monday but this could easily be changed to using self in an extension and/or returning self or the given date instead of nil